# Vertical Line plot by bar Index(TradingView Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Is it possible to write a script that will plot a vertical line at 20, 50 and 200 bars back from the current bar?

I am currently using the "Anchored Vertical Line" indicator, but I cant see the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vline()](https://www.tradingview.com/script/EmTkvfCM-vline-Function-for-Pine-Script-v4-0/) for that.

```
//@version=4
study("vline() Function for Pine Script v4.0+", overlay=true)

vline(BarIndex, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) => // Verticle Line Function, ≈50-54 lines maximum allowable per indicator
    // return = line.new(BarIndex,   0.0, BarIndex,     100.0, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=false) and RSI, Stochastic, etc...
    // return = line.new(BarIndex,  -1.0, BarIndex,       1.0, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=false) and +/-1.0 oscillators
    return = line.new(BarIndex, low - tr, BarIndex, high + tr, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=true)

if(bar_index%10==0.0) // Generically plots a line every 10 bars
    vline(bar_index, #FF8000ff, line.style_solid, 1) // Variable assignment not required
```

Comment: How would I manipulate this script to only show 1 vertical line at 20 bars back from the current?